# Core Results Web Part - Fixed keyword query - examples?

Tags: web-part, search, search-results

I'm experimenting with **Core Results Web Part**.

According to
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394509.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872310.aspx

I should be able to write something like
`Url:*community* AND Url:*Lists/Members*` to bring up results where **Url** contains *community* word in it as well as (and only if) also it has *Lists/Members* in it.

It doesn't work at all. I also tried just simply putting `url:*community*` and it still shows me random results where it can find both URL and community somewhere in the title, description etc.

What am I missing?

Comment: In what way is the "community" term used within the url?  Is it a managed path or a site name?

Comment: It is part of the Url. eg. `http://mysharepoint.com/community/Lists/Members` . I pretty much only want results where Url contains those two terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
path:community AND path:lists/members
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why not Url:? or any tutorials and documentation that I might find useful?

Comment: My answer is mostly based on the prior experience working with KQL. Using the "path" managed property works with both SharePoint Server Search and FAST Search but the "url" managed property is not searchable by default in FS4SP. Wildcard operator "*" only works for prefix matching - using it in front of the search term produces the unexpected results you get.